# Getting 403 error on url while sending POST

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-403

I am getting started with a django based simple ajax enabled web app.

I am able to launch the hompage. From homepage when i try to hit another url I am getting 403 error

My index page is http://mydomain.com/SampleApp - This works fine

My Ajax url is http://mydomain.com/SampleApp/ajax - This gives 403 error

Please replace 'mydomain.com' in above urls with proper localhost:8000 as it is restricted.

The error shown is

**CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Reason given for failure:
    CSRF cookie not set.**

I think I am missing some important setting in settings.py

Adding the source code

URL Conf

```
url(r'^SampleApp/', include('views.urls'))
```

views.url.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^ajax/$', views.ajax),
    url(r'^$', views.index)
)
```

views.views.py

```
def index(request):
    print('Rendering Index')
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def ajax(request):
    print('rendering ajax')
    return render(request, 'ajax.html');
```

For the sake of brevity, I have excluded the imports

Comment: Do you have some .htaccess file?
PD: It give me a 404 error no 403

Comment: No HtAccess files. I get Forbidden (403) error as a well formatted html.

Comment: Add context_instance=RequestContext(request) in every view that you use form. Let me guess you use render_to_response

Comment: are you sending the csrf token in your ajax request? django documentation provides javascript code samples on how to do this

Comment: @catherine I ve added the source code snippet

Comment: All, I ve for now commented CSRF middleware `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` to proceed with learning django MVC

Comment: just add csrf decorator in your view

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you did not put `csrfmiddlewaretoken` in your ajax request.
The easiest way to include it is:

```
var data = {
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
        // any other data
    },
    url = '/api/create/';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
    ...
```

And don't forget to include `{% csrf_token %}` in your template of page from which the ajax request is sent (like index.html)

Or you can decorate your view by `@csrf_exempt` decorator:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def ajax(request):
    print('rendering ajax')
    return render(request, 'ajax.html');
```

This allows you to exclude `csrfmiddlewaretoken` from ajax request

Hope that'll help you.